After Adding VueDevTools to vitePlugins happened: Internal server error: EPERM
After adding VueDevTools to vitePlugins, running the program in the development mode will trigger the error:
npm run dev
ERROR [vite] Internal server error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\System Volume Information'                                                                          23:47:18  
  Plugin: vite:import-glob
  File: D:/nodejs/project/naive-ui-admin-main/node_modules/.pnpm/vite-plugin-vue-devtools@7.2.1_rollup@2.79.1_vite@3.2.7_@types+node@18.17.4_less@4.2.0_terser@5.19.2__vue@3.3.4/node_modules/vite-plugin-vue-devtools/src/overlay.js

/build/vite/plugin/index.ts:

import type { Plugin, PluginOption } from 'vite';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { NaiveUiResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx';
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools';

import { configHtmlPlugin } from './html';
import { configMockPlugin } from './mock';
import { configCompressPlugin } from './compress';

export function createVitePlugins(viteEnv: ViteEnv, isBuild: boolean, prodMock) {
  const { VITE_USE_MOCK, VITE_BUILD_COMPRESS, VITE_BUILD_COMPRESS_DELETE_ORIGIN_FILE } = viteEnv;

  const vitePlugins: (Plugin | Plugin[] | PluginOption[] | any)[] = [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    VueDevTools(),

    Components({
      dts: true,
      resolvers: [NaiveUiResolver()],
    }),
  ];

  // vite-plugin-html
  vitePlugins.push(configHtmlPlugin(viteEnv, isBuild));

  // vite-plugin-mock
  VITE_USE_MOCK && vitePlugins.push(configMockPlugin(isBuild, prodMock));

  if (isBuild) {
    // rollup-plugin-gzip
    vitePlugins.push(
      configCompressPlugin(VITE_BUILD_COMPRESS, VITE_BUILD_COMPRESS_DELETE_ORIGIN_FILE)
    );
  }

  return vitePlugins;
}


reinstall vue
reinstall vite-plugin-vue-devtools
run VSCode in Admin

remove VueDevTools can eliminate the error!

Why do you need that one for? Isn't the browser extension enough? https://devtools.vuejs.org/
